# Laravel blade perfectly good @foreach loop crash when nested

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I don't understand why just nesting loops should throw a `Trying to get property of non-object` error when they run fine if separate. The code is identical (apart from nesting) and underlying data objects don't change, and they don't reference each other.

**This works:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title','welcome')

@section('content')

<h1 align=center>INVESTMENTS</h1>
<table align=center border=1>
<tr>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
</tr>
@foreach ($investment_accounts as $investment_account)
        <tr><th><h2>{{$investment_account->investment_institution_name}}</h2></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
@endforeach

@foreach ($investment_item as $investment_item)

        <tr><th><h4 align=center><b>{{$investment_item->investment_name}}</b></br></h4></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Quantity: {{$investment_item->investment_quantity}}</br> </td>
        <td>Fair Market Value: ${{number_format($investment_item->investment_sale_price_fmv,2)}}</br> </td>
        <td>Unit cost: ${{number_format(floatval($investment_item->investment_sale_price_fmv)/intval($investment_item->investment_quantity),2)}}</td>
        </tr>
        <hr>

@endforeach

@endsection
```

**But this bombs:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title','welcome')

@section('content')

<h1 align=center>INVESTMENTS</h1>
<table align=center border=1>
<tr>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
</tr>
@foreach ($investment_accounts as $investment_account)
        <tr><th><h2>{{$investment_account->investment_institution_name}}</h2></th><th></th><th></th></tr>

    @foreach ($investment_item as $investment_item)

            <tr><th><h4 align=center><b>{{$investment_item->investment_name}}</b></br></h4></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Quantity: {{$investment_item->investment_quantity}}</br> </td>
            <td>Fair Market Value: ${{number_format($investment_item->investment_sale_price_fmv,2)}}</br> </td>
            <td>Unit cost: ${{number_format(floatval($investment_item->investment_sale_price_fmv)/intval($investment_item->investment_quantity),2)}}</td>
            </tr>
            <hr>

    @endforeach

@endforeach

@endsection
```

I'm working in Laravel 5.5 with XAMPP/PHP7
Any ideas?

Comment: `$investment_item as $investment_item`. Do you mean `$investment_items as $investment_item`?

Comment: `$investment_item as $investment_item` doesn't seems right. I guess you typed the variable name wrong. "Trying to get property of non-object" error throws when you try to access a property which doesn't exists or if the object is null. Can you share the full error message you have encountered?

Comment: @Marwelln and @Iftieaq, the variable names are correct (though I agree it doesn't follow the Laravel single-as-plural convention). I have tried different names, such as `$investment_item as $item` but it doesn't matter. The error is the same and the reference shouldn't matter as long as I use it correctly. Please note that those items are the same in the working version as with the broken one.

Comment: @ Iftieaq, the full error text is not of much additional help, but here it is: `ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\datatables\resources\views\investments.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with your inner loop is that you have named both the variables the same:

```
// incorrect
@foreach ($investment_item as $investment_item)

// correct
@foreach ($investment_items as $investment_item)
```

Your first example works because it loops exactly one time. With the nested loop, `$investment_item` is still scoped within the first loop, hence the crash.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I have to use `$investment_item` for the collection name but when I changed this to `@foreach ($investment_item as $single_item)` it worked.  I had thought of this before, but I missed changing one of the field references in the loop and didn't notice that the error had changed, Many thanks - you saved me!!!

Answer (score 0):

nesting loops is not really a good practice. It produces undesirable result since the outer loop kind of finish execution before even the inner loop completes a circle. the best approach is to declare a function outside the loop, run the second loop in the function. finally call the function from the first loop ie

```
function myFunction(){
    for(u in someObject){
        // doing something
    }
}

for(x in someObject){
    myFunction();
}
```

method above will always produce better result. Although in C programming, looping inside a loop is common when using multi-dimensional array!, to me it kind of sucks.

Comment: @Olantunji, thank you. Per your suggestion I'm looking into how to use a function in a Laravel blade file. It would seem that I should create the function in either my model or in a helper file for the blade. However, this seems overly complicated for what I want to achieve which is iterate through a group of sub records for each parent loop.

Comment: I'm still perplexed as to why moving one loop into the other breaks this when they are not modifying or effecting each other. I have done this nested iteration many times before but not in a Laravel blade and I'm trying to understand what I've stumbled upon and how to correct it. The function suggestion would seem more of a workaround, though I do greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @OlantunjiOdelade  `the outer loop kind of finish execution before even the inner loop completes a circle.`

This is incorrect, the code is not executing asynchronously. In fact the exact opposite is more the case, the inner loop will complete every iteration before the outer loop completes even one. It is really never a good idea to declare functions in a view file.